# Eclipse - Wrong string appears

Tags: android, eclipse, string

I wanted to change the text in my Hello World app to Hello Android.
So, I've changes this line:

```
android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

To

```
android:text="@string/hello_android" />
```

I have also created a string in the strings.xml file:
Name: hello_android
Value: Hello Android!

When looking at my graphical layout, everything seems in order: the text says Hello Android.
But when running it in an emulator, it still says Hello World.

What did I miss?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me a lot. The emulator doesn't always start the new version of the application, but resumes a running instance.
Try uninstalling the App from the emulator and compile the code again :)

Comment: What really? This never happened to me before.

Comment: Yes... I'm using Xamarin Studio with Visual Studio 2012 plugin, which might cause the problem. Don't know if this happens in Eclipse.

Comment: I agree with @Ahmad and also the op has tagged eclipse.

Comment: Oh it wasn't about Eclipse. I'm a newbie at this so I wouldn't know if it would fix the problem anyway. It has changes somehow in my workspace, but when running it in an AVD... nothing happens

Comment: @Wezzz I think you just hold the app-icon and drag it up.


Ahmad: Yeah well, it seems to me that OP did everything correct, so I'm just trying to find the error :)

Comment: Nope, doesn't work... :(. Or maybe I have understood you wrong... I'm now looking at my Run Defaults...

Comment: @Janman No worries. I just thought this might occur for others. I, for myself haven't had the problem (yet thankfully) :)

Comment: @Wezzz
If the Graphical Layout in Eclipse displays the correct text, I'm sure you code is fine (unless you change the text programmatically?).
Please try to use another emulator device or create the app with another name.

Comment: Others do the same. But it might be the problem that the emulator is really slow... I'' try some other stuff tomorrow, or maybe may book with a course has an answer (I was running ahead with things, so that might be a problem ;). We'll see).

Answer (score 0):

Try a full Clean on your project and then run the application. Sometimes when you make changes to string,layouts,ids (stuff that have a specific ID in your R file) Eclipse creates a mess of those IDs, and as a result you get the error you see.

If a simple, clean and build doesn't change anything, try uninstalling the app and running the project again.

If neither worked, check if you have multiple files with strings that contain the same string with different values.